# the group policy client service failed to start due to the following error: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a

Tags: windows-8.1, services, group-policy, runtime-error

I am having an issue where when I log on to my laptop briefly I get notification that reads `The Group Policy Client service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.`

[image]

When I go to Event Viewer I can see bunch of errors.

`Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          20/09/2015 23:15:48
Event ID:      7000
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      xxx
Description:
The Group Policy Client service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7000</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-09-20T22:15:48.478373600Z" />
    <EventRecordID>9162</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="644" ThreadID="2564" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>xxx</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Group Policy Client</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">%%1053</Data>
    <Binary>670070007300760063000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>`

I also noticed that my updates haven't been runing for a around six weeks.

**Has anyone experienced something simmilar and how did you fix it?**

Comment: You could try doing an 'sfc /scannow' to see if that helps clean up some underlying OS issues.

Comment: @Nixphoe Hi, this did it, ran from cmd as admin, then restarted machine no new entries on Group policy in event log could you please post it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try doing an `sfc /scannow` to see if that helps clean up some underlying OS issues.

1. Go to find and type `cmd` then click right mouse button and choose `run as administrator`

[image]

2. Then type into window that opened  `sfc /scannow`

[image]

It should then run for a while.